# Beautify URL on Google App Engine PHP Static Website

Tags: php, google-app-engine

I am developing a static website for my friend with some light vanilla PHP code. There is a .php on the url on every page such as xxxxx.com/service.php. I did some research and found out that tweaking on `app.yaml` is not an elagance method as it will not handling error 404 gracefully. What is in my mind is that I can create a special PHP file taking in request that end with .php from `app.yaml` and process each request like `.htaccess`. Due to my lacking of PHP knowledge, I am not able to produce the code in the file. Please enlighten me on the process.

Below is my `app.yaml`

```
runtime: php55
api_version: 1
instance_class: F1
automatic_scaling:
  max_idle_instances: 1
  min_pending_latency: 30ms
  max_instances: 1

handlers:
- url: /css
  static_dir: css
  secure: always

- url: /js
  static_dir: js
  secure: always

- url: /images
  static_dir: images
  secure: always

- url: /fonts
  static_dir: fonts
  secure: always

- url: /sitemap\.xml
  static_files: sitemap.xml
  upload: sitemap.xml
  secure: always

- url: /
  script: index.php
  secure: always

- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
  secure: always

- url: /.*
  script: 404.php
  secure: always
```

Comment: By "Beautify", are you asking for a request to `example.com/myimage` to open `/images/myimage.jpg`?  Or `example.com/myscript` to open `/scripts/myscript.php`?  Or?

Comment: @GAEfan I am so sorry for the unclear problem statement.Yes basically I am asking for a request for `example.com/about` instead of `example.com/about.php`. For the static files, we can just ignore it. In summary, I just need the url that end with `.php` to be beautify, with the capability to handle 404 and serve custom 404.php file for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure all your static files are already handled in `app.yaml`, and root (`/`) is handled, that means anything left would go to a script.  So, your final handler could be:

```
- url: /(.+)
  script: \1.php
```

I would leave the

```
- url: /(.+\.php)$
  script: \1
```

handler above it, as the penultimate handler, so a person can go to `/about` or `/about.php` and it will handle both.

```
- url: /(.+)\.php$
  script: \1.php
```

Perhaps redirect the `.php` version to beautified, so users adapt over time without getting a `404`:

```
- url: /(.+)\.php$
  script: redirect.php
```

**redirect.php:**

```
<?php

    require_once __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

    $app = new Silex\Application();

    $app->get('/{scriptName}.php', function($scriptName) {
        header('Location: https://www.example.com/NewAbout/{$scriptName}');
        exit();
    })

?>
```

**Update:**
To handle `404`s, you need a list (like you would in .htaccess) of valid URLs to catch.  You can do this using regex in `app.yaml`.  Then, to handle `404`s, you finish with a catchall handler:

```
- url: /(home|about|contact|page1|page99|etc)$ ## the pipe (|) means "or"
  script: \1.php


- url: /.*
  script: 404.php
```

Then you write a simple 404.php script page to display the proper message and deliver a `404` http response.

Comment: I am trying to get a solution that able to handle custom 404 well with a `.htaccess`-like php script rather than doing it in `app.yaml` which unable to handle 404 + beautify the url. The solution you suggested can be found in other post in stackoverflow, which is not exactly the one I am looking for.

Comment: one more problem will be the internal link. For example when you click on a menu component, Service for instance, the `<a>` tag will include a `href` which will link to `service.php`. In this case, the route is still contains `.php`

Comment: Yes, `- url: /(.+)\.php$` handles that.

Comment: It will not beautify the url right? It just able to handle the route to serve the file but the url will contains `.php`

Comment: I do not understand.  Do you want someone to get a proper response if they enter `/service.php`?  Or a `404`?

Comment: With the script suggested by you, I tried and encounter some troubles. When I type in `example.com/service`, it will serve the `service.php` properly. But when I click on the navbar `service` which contain the `href='service.php`,  it will serve the `service.php` page correctly, but the URL still appear as `example.com/service.php` instead of `example.com/service`.

Comment: In order to change the url in the address bar, you need to do a redirect to the beautified url.  Make `service.php` redirect to `service`

Comment: Where to add the redirection code? `app.yaml` as well?

Comment: With the addition of `redirect.php` code, is that I need to include some framework in my project and package management like `Composer`? I am doing the static web with vanilla php.

Comment: Yes.  You can use Composer to install packages need.  The code example I showed uses Silex (Symfony).  Many tutorials to show you how to set this up.